# Google api + php + codeigniter + curl

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, google-signin

i have a code in google api url now how i can convert it to access token ??
i used curl but it is not working.
any batter and easy idea i have to used that in codeigniter.
and what is that authorization_code?

```
<?php 

$field='code='.$_REQUEST['code'].'&client_id=clirnt-id  
&client_secret=client-secret
&redirect_uri=http: // localost/googleapi/curlreq.php
&grant_type=authorization_code';



$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$field);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo 'end';

echo '<br/>';
 //echo $server_output;
print_r($server_output);

curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: i get this by Hybrid Auth. it is giving all the apis yahoo,fb,g+,twitter everthing ..it really good

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get access token.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_PUBLIC_API_ACCESS_KEY");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://yourdomain.com/oauthCallback');

$access_token = '';

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {

    redirect($client->createAuthUrl());

} else {

    // Exchanging code with access token
    $client->authenticate(urldecode($_GET['code'])); // Exchange code for auth

    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken(); // Get access token

    // Send your curl request to any api with access token here and get data

}
```

This is the general flow. You should first take look at the [implementing OAuth here in official documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_web).

Once you have access token you can make REST call to any api, but before that you must specify scopes which feature you want to access.